# Converting TIFF to PDF results in Insufficient Data For Image

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, tiff, pdfsharp

I have a utility that converts batches of TIFF images to PDFs using the PDFSharp library.  The following code performs the actual conversion.  When I open the resulting PDF files in Acrobat Reader, I receive an error message for certain ones stating "Insufficient Data for Image."  Others are fine.

What could be causing this?  Is there anything I'm missing in the code that could prevent this?

```
Public Shared Function ConvertImageToPDF(ByVal img As Image) As Byte()
    Using ms As New MemoryStream()
        Using pdf As New PdfDocument()
            Dim pageCount = GetPageCount(img)

            For index = 0 To (pageCount - 1)
                Dim page = New PdfPage()

                Using sourceImage = GetPage(img, index)
                    Using pageImage = XImage.FromGdiPlusImage(sourceImage)
                        page.Width = pageImage.PointWidth
                        page.Height = pageImage.PointHeight

                        pdf.Pages.Add(page)

                        Using xgr = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(pdf.Pages(index))
                            xgr.DrawImage(pageImage, 0, 0)
                        End Using
                    End Using
                End Using
            Next

            pdf.Save(ms, False)
            pdf.Close()
        End Using

        Return ms.ToArray()
    End Using
End Function

Public Shared Function GetPageCount(ByVal img As Image) As Integer
    If (img Is Nothing) Then
        Return -1
    End If

    Return img.GetFrameCount(FrameDimension.Page)
End Function

Public Shared Function GetPage(ByVal img As Image, ByVal pageNumber As Integer) As Image
    img.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Page, pageNumber)

    Dim ms = New MemoryStream()
    img.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Tiff)

    Return Image.FromStream(ms)
End Function
```

UPDATE:

If I run the same code over the same TIFF files, then the PDF files that were corrupt before are now OK, and ones that were OK before are now corrupt.

UPDATE 2:

After reviewing this connect issue (https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/584681/system-drawing-image-flags-has-different-value-in-vista-and-windows-7) and the community comment on this MSDN page (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.save.aspx), it appears the issue is related to an operating system level bug in Windows 7.  Can anyone confirm this or offer a workaround?

Comment: Which PDFsharp version, which build? If you currently use the WPF build, please try the GDI+ build (or vice versa) to check if the problem occurs in both builds. Which Windows version?

Comment: @PDFsharpTeam I'm using PDFsharp Version 1.31 GDI+ build on Windows 7.

Comment: @PDFsharpTeam I also tried it with the WPF build and that had the same problem.

Comment: Does the process using PDFSharp have to decode and re-encode the images? It looks like it might due to that "draw" function. I've written a command line utility to do the same thing that is very efficient (no decode/recode, just repackage the image data). Please contact me if you would like to give it a try; you can be a free tester of the code.

Comment: The best workaround for Windows 7 bugs: use Windows XP. Seriously: PDFsharp uses the operating system to read image files (thus profiting of the various formats supported by Windows), but with Windows 7 they introduced bugs (certain JPEG files are not handled correctly, now there seems to be a problem with TIFF files, too).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in my update, after reviewing this connect issue (https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/584681/system-drawing-image-flags-has-different-value-in-vista-and-windows-7) and the community comment on this MSDN page (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.save.aspx), it appears the issue is related to an operating system level bug in Windows 7.

This is supported by the comment from PDFsharpTeam.

In addition, when the images are read in Windows XP, the flags property on the image object is set to 77888.  On Win7, it is set to 77840.  After reviewing the MSDN documentation for the flags property (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.flags.aspx), the difference is that WinXP flagged the image as a grayscale image (which mine are), but Win7 flagged it as an RGB image.  This appears to be a symptom of the problem, but I don't know enough about image formats and color spaces to speak with authority on this.

**UPDATE (2014-06-13):**

After continuing to experience this problem, I researched a bit further and found a post on the PDFSharp forums mentioning this issue and linking to another post with a fix.

http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=2729

http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?p=5967#p5967

Basically, there are two methods in the `PdfImage.FaxEncode.cs` file that need to be updated.

In both the `CountOneBits()` and `CountZeroBits()` methods, replace the following code:

```
return found + hits;
```

with

```
found += hits;
if (found >= bitsLeft)
  return bitsLeft;
return found;
```

Comment: is there a solution/workaround for this bug?  We have the same issue with an application that user with upgraded Laptops running windows 7 are now facing .

Comment: @techventure: I never found a good solution for this.  Running on Windows XP seems to be the best workaround.  For one of our clients with Windows 7, we ran the application inside a Windows XP virtual machine and that seems to be fine.  There is a PropertyItems property for the System.Drawing.Image class.  The contents of this property were also different between the images that worked and images that did not, in case you want to investigate this further.

Comment: I found that cloning the image (one for each page if there are multiple pages) solved the issue.